# Change the img src attribute using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having trouble on changing the img src attribute of my image tag using jQuery. Here is my code

```
 $(".img-thumb").on("mouseover", function (e) {
     $val = ($(e.currentTarget).attr('src'))
     $val = $val.slice(1,200));
     $('#preview').attr('src','$val');
 });
```

Then on my tag

```
    <div id="zoom-in" style="width:750px;height:410px;margin-left:60px;border:1px solid black;border-radius:20px;overflow:hidden;">
       <img id="preview" style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="gallery/Comme_/Al Fardan Jewellery/img.jpg" alt=""/>
    </div>
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

If you put the variable name inside quotes then it will be used as a string.

```
$('#preview').attr('src', $val);
                          ^^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to pass `$val` as variable not a string,

```
$('#preview').attr('src', $val);
```

Comment: It is still not working but the value of the path is correct.

Comment: @Mr.Hans Check `console.log($val)` inside that event.

Comment: where can i find the console.log? sorry im a newbie here

Comment: Its a normal javascript code. Just insert this line `alert($val)` before setting the src attribute. And tell us what is getting displayed as an alert.

Comment: I already did that and the path is correct. But the image was not change.

Comment: Then try to open that path in a new window and check whether it is 404 or not.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the quotes. `$val` is a JavaScript variable:

```
$('#preview').attr('src', $val);
```

Comment: It is still not working but the value of the path is correct.

Comment: Where can i find the console.log? sorry im a newbie here

Comment: @Mr.Hans Press `F12`.

Comment: @Mr.Hans Having the console open, refresh the page.

Comment: So what was the issue then @Mr.Hans?